# Shortest way of checking whether a string starts with a specified set of substrings

Tags: python, string

I have a string `color_line` which I need to check whether it starts with a substring which takes values only in `'red'`, `'blue'`, `'green'`, or `'magenta'`.

Is there a shorter way of doing the check than the obvious way of

```
if line.startswith( 'red' ) or ... or line.startswith( 'magenta' ): ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a tuple of values to [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```
if line.startswith(('red', 'blue', 'green', 'magenta')):
```

Comment: In general, would this work for a general boolean function `f( x )` and `x` is a variable that takes values in a list `li`?  Your answer suggests `if f( tuple( li ) ):`.

Comment: No.  In that case, you would want to use `any` and a generator expression: `if any(f(x) for x in li):`  My answer was for the problem you stated in your question.

Comment: If you have a list of values you want to use with `str.startswith`, you just need to call `tuple()` on it:  `if line.startswith(tuple(li)):`.

Comment: @iCodez Hi, please follow this initiative and invite other people: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/85335/tkinter-and-ttk

Comment: @Rinzler - I have looked over your proposal, and appreciate being invited, but I am not sure I want to commit to it.  An entire site for just Tkinter/Ttk questions is too limited (as per the guidelines listed [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/merging-season/).  The [tkinter] tag only has 340 followers and SO is currently handling these type of questions just fine.  If anything, a site for [Windows Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/winforms/info) would be more useful than one for Tkinter/Ttk.  I think it is best to leave Tkinter/Ttk questions to SO for now.

Comment: @iCodez I am doing this because there's no dedicated up-to-date forum just for tkinter, and I think it's useful, and it deserves its own website. If you change idea, you know where to find it.

Comment: @iCodez We are already 4 people, and I am the less expert between us, so I think that there's people that believe in this initiative.